# How to refactor following if else statements in Python

Tags: python, refactoring

So I have two functions in both of which I'm doing similar conditional check but with different expressions:

```py
def do_stuff_1(data, config):
  if config[KEY] == "condition1":
    return convert_data_1(data)
  elif config[KEY] == "condition2":
    return convert_data_2(data)
  else:
    return convert_data_3(data)
```

```py
def do_stuff_2(data, config):
  if config[KEY] == "condition1":
    return serialize_data_1(data)
  elif config[KEY] == "condition2":
    return serialize_data_2(data)
  else:
    return serialize_data_3(data)
```

Is there a way to refactor these two functions and extract common if else logic?

tried to refactor but haven't figured out how I should do.

Edit: To clarify, these two functions need to be in sequence. The data in do_stuff_2 depends on do_stuff_1
The caller looks something like this:

```py
dict = {}
while(some_condition):
  dict.update(do_stuff_1(get_data(), config))

result = do_stuff_2(dict, config)
```

Comment: is data in parameter `do_stuff_2` is returned value from `do_stuff_1`?

Comment: Try replacing the if-else with switch case

Comment: @Rizquuula - yeah, sort of, check the update.

Comment: @anosha_rehan - switch won't help. It will still end up with two similar switch clauses

Comment: do you have serilize all data together? I mean can you do `serialize_data_2(convert_data_2(data))` ?

Comment: You could make another function with the if-else/switch logic. And call it from both `do_stuff_1` and `do_stuff_2`. That would remove the redundancy

Comment: @SadraNaddaf - There are multiple data to be processed before serialization. i.e. do_stuff_1 will be called multiple times with different data before do_stuff_2 gets called

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand your convert and serialize function names are different so these functions are performing different tasks. Hope this might help you.

```
def do_stuff(data, config, convert = false, serialize = false):
    if config[KEY] == "condition1":
        if convert == true:
            return convert_data_1(data)
        if serialize == true:
            return serialize_data_1(data)
    elif config[KEY] == "condition2":
        if convert == true:
            return convert_data_2(data)
        if serialize == true:
            return serialize_data_2(data)
    else:
      if convert == true:
          return convert_data_3(data)
      if serialize == true:
          return serialize_data_3(data)
```